# How to add brackets using AutoHotKey

Tags: text, autohotkey, brackets, keystroke

I want to create a hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>(</kbd> that adds brackets to a phrase. I.e select `x-1` to get `(x-1)`. How to program this function?

I write a lot of phrases such as: `x+1/(x-1)^2` so it would be helpful to have a hotkey to add brackets.

Comment: Where do you have problems? Show us your code.

Comment: Sounds like you just need this sequence: cut selection, insert `(`, paste, insert `)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(::
SendInput, ^c
Sleep 10
Clipboard = (%Clipboard%)
SendInput, ^v
return
```

This implies that you are actually pressing CTRL+SHIFT+9 (since you don't have a `(` key).

I did a quick test and it will add round brackets to anything you highlight.  I would recommend tweaking the trigger key since CTRL+SHIFT+9 isn't that easy to hit, but otherwise seems to work without issues.

If you want to save the clipboard, then you'll have to do this:

```
^(::
SavedClipboard := ClipboardAll
SendInput, ^c
Sleep 10
Clipboard = (%Clipboard%)
SendInput, ^v
Clipboard := SavedClipboard
SavedClipboard =
return
```

Comment: Just note that I'm mixing assignment operator of = and :=, which have different behavior.  It is coded very quickly, but might be confusing to read for a beginner.  AutoHotKey has a help file that will tell you what the difference is.

Comment: There is one more. How can I change your script to add brackets and immidiately rewind to inside of brackets?
I.e. I use right SHIFT + key "(" to get this "( )" where it repositions the cursor/pointer inside the brackets?

Comment: You should be able to CTRL+LeftArrow to do that.  
I hesitate to setup a hotkey for SHIFT + 9 because, well, it'll probably loop trigger with the above hotkey, and you also will lose access to the left round bracket :)  

It is actually easier to setup the cursor to automatically do that every time than to trigger based on another hotkey, so think about what you want to do first and let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you respone. Well, it should be best to have them both for the same hotkey. In other words, when I select a phrase, only then it adds brackets to the selected pharse. Or when I just type (none selected) then it adds empty brackets where the cursor/pointer repositions inside. Is it possible to make it?

Comment: Or you probably can do this by using a Mouse hotkey instead of a keyboard.  

Change `^(::` to `^RButton::` so CTRL+Right Click will do the bracketing thing, then you can just reposition the cursor with your mouse instead.